# class->...->function()

Tags: php, вконтакте

не подскажете возможно ли реализовать что-то вроде
`vk.messages.send()`, только на php?

я предполагая будет что-то вроде `$vk->messages->send()`, хотя возможно так сделать нельзя, но если есть альтернативные варианты, то тоже предлагайте.

Comment: Ищи method chaining

Comment: У меня основной сутью является то чтобы вызывать функцию можно было только тогда когда например обращаешься к так называемой под функции. То есть нельзя использовать функцию какую-то без вызова под функции. При чем под функции могут быть разные, и от этого должен зависит функции которые можно вызывать

Comment: У меня не стоит задача вызывать кучу функций друг за другом, об этом я и так знал. Просто стало интересно возможно ли реализовать под функции в php так же как и скажем в c#? Где можно спокойно писать класс, далее обращение идёт даже не к функции, а я не знаю к чему, а далее уже к функции

Comment: В php абсолютно так же, вы можете создать класс, в котором будет членом класса messages объект другого класса, в котором есть уже функция send

Comment: ну так в php же нельзя вроде бы создавать class в class.

Comment: Или вы имеете введу что можно создать 2 класса, и в 1 подключить все остальные(extends)?